# Writing all your functions in one cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

What if I put multiple function inside a single cloud function so that its instance lives at max and that I will have to deal with cold start once?

**Why is this a bad idea?**

```
export const shop = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  switch (data.type) {

    case "get_fruits":
      return await getFruits();

    case "place_order":
      return await placeOrder();

    case "add_to_cart":
      return await addToCart();

    default:
      return;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is pretty much what any express web app you run on Cloud Functions for Firebase does. Why do you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Because I thought that the way to do it is have a different cloud function for every function. So then I thought this was a maybe a Hackish way to eliminate cold start time.

Comment: Agree, it's not a good idea (IMO). Other services, like Cloud Run, allow you running a real web app, to expose standard REST API. Maybe too powerful at the beginning, the evolution of your services will be easier than performing yourselves the routing with your hack.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in too @guillaumeblaquiere   Can you elaborate **why** it wouldn't be a good idea on Cloud Functions (I get that Cloud Run is better for this sort of concurrency control)? With those additions, it probably worth posting as an answer 

Answer (score 2):

It will work but, IMO, it's not a good thing to do. There are many principles and patterns that exist today and that you do not enforce your solution.

**Microservice**

One of them is the split in microservices. There is no problem to build a monolith, but when I'm seeing your example (get_fruit, place_order, add_to_cart), I'm seeing different roles and responsibilities. I love the separation of concern: 1 service does 1 thing.

**Routing**

But, maybe your service is only a service for the routing and call functions deployed independently (and you enforce the microservice principle). If so, your service can become a bottleneck, if there are a lot of entries and a lot of queries.

In addition, there are services dedicated for routing: load balancers. They use the URL path of the requests and reach the correct microservices to serve them

**Developer usage**

Yes a URL, not a field in the body of your message to route the traffic. Today, the developers are familiar with the REST API. To get the fruit, they perform a GET request to the `/fruit` URL and they know they will get the fruits. If they want to add to the cart, they perform a POST request to the `/cart` URL and it works!

You USE URL, standard REST definition, load balancers and microservices.

You can imagine other benefits:

- Each microservice can scale independently (you can have more get_fruit request than place_order, the service scale differently)
- The security is easier to control (no security to get the catalog (fruits)), but you have to be authenticated to place an order
- Evolution velocity can be decoupled between the services
- ...