# Firebase functions: Is it better to separate entry point for every operation or have a single entry point?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

What is the best practice when using Firebase functions?

1: One function as an entry point for multiple operations (micro framework behind a single entry point)

2: Separate function for every operation.

What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Good comment chain from earlier today on the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73259819

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing all your functions in one cloud function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73259819/writing-all-your-functions-in-one-cloud-function)

Comment: @MarkAnthonyB yes and no. I am more curious about the technical limitations. How many requests per minute will it handle? Does google enforce any memory limitations ?